# C# Unable to Bind EmailMessage

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, eml

I have a method which converts `Email` to `.eml` format.

However, the statement of `EmailMessage.Bind` suddenly stops working without any error.

Below is my code snippet:

```
public static string convertEmailToEml(EmailMessage emailMessage, string caseNumber, string EMLSaveFilePath)
{
    Console.WriteLine(emailMessage.Subject); //correct value
    Console.WriteLine(caseNumber); //correct value
    Console.WriteLine(EMLSaveFilePath); //correct value
    Console.WriteLine(emailMessage.Id); //correct value


    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    PropertySet props = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent);

    var email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, emailMessage.Id, props); //not executed
    string emlFullPath = EMLSaveFilePath + caseNumber + ".eml"; //not executed

    Console.WriteLine(emlFullPath); //code not reached
    Console.ReadKey();

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(emlFullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        fs.Write(email.MimeContent.Content, 0, email.MimeContent.Content.Length);
    }
    return emlFullPath;
}
```

May I know if there are any places that I can look into?

There were `warning` messages upon solution building as follows, not sure if they are linked:

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent
>   assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are
>   listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

**Exception Thrown during Debug Mode:**

> 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceLocalException' in
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll("The Url property of the
>   ExchangeService object must be set.")

I have verified that `service`, `emailMessage.Id`, and `props` values are not `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation for `EmailMessage.Bind(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.bind?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_EmailMessage_Bind_Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_ExchangeService_Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_ItemId_Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_PropertySet_), it states that this method results in a call to Exchange Web Services (EWS).

You create an instance of `ExchangeService` but you do not provide a URL to it ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.url?view=exchange-ews-api)). This is a requirement. The exception that is thrown is pointing you directly at the missing data.